# Simular pulsación de una tecla (Tab) al cargar una página (javascript/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una página de login de mi aplicación, en la que quiero que, bajo unas determinadas circustancias, se simule la pulsación de "Tab" tras cargar la página. Tengo bastante claro que debe ser en $(window).load, aunque no estoy del todo seguro. Pero la pulsación soy incapaz de simularla. He visto que se propone la función trigger, pero no veo como puede ayudarme. Siento no poner nada del código, pero imagino que en este caso ayudaría poco.

```
$(window).load(function () {
     // "Pulsar" tecla tab 
 });
```

Comment: Cuando te refieres a simular el pulsar la tecla Tab, ¿te refieres al comportamiento de que coge el foco del primer objeto?¿O necesitas ex profeso que se active el keycode 9 (el de la tecla tab)? Te pregunto porque hacer lo primero es mucho más fácil de hacer en cualquier navegador que lo segundo.

Comment: Como comenta @MikelFerreiro, esta pregunta tiene pinta de problema XY: ¿necesitas el evento "pulsar Tab" o necesitas que el cursor se ponga en un determinado "input"?

Comment: @MikelFerreiro Necesito que se active el keycode 9. Que bajo determinadas circustancias gane el foco el segundo control lo he probado pero no me vale. El problema es que InternetExplorer no me está mostrando la contraseña guardada para el usuario hasta que no se hace "tab" desde el campo nombre al de la password

Comment: Insistiendo un poco en la inquietud de @PabloLozano, ¿podrías decirnos qué es lo que quieres hacer simplemente, independientemente de si tecla tab o no tecla tab? Parece que lo que quieres es trasladar el foco a un determinado elemento. No veo por qué haya que forzar el pulsado de una tecla para eso. A mi juicio ese tipo de comportamientos que lanzan acciones sin contar con el usuario no son buenos desde el punto de vista de UX. No es lo mismo pulsar una tecla en lugar del usuario (nunca haría eso en programación) que trasladar el foco.